# Is componentDidUpdate called if and only if render is called?

Tags: reactjs

React components have a `render` method and can have a `componentDidUpdate` method. My question is: does `componentDidUpdate` get called after *every* render, and are there any times where `componentDidUpdate` gets called but `render` is not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`componentDidUpdate` is always called after `render`. So if you prevent render with `shouldComponentUpdate` for example, `didUpdate` will never get called

**Are there any times where componentDidUpdate gets called but render is not?**

No, `componentDidUpdate` depends on `render` to be invoked. But the oposite can happen, `componentDidUpdate` [doesn't get called after the first render](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)